# Remote domain is not an IDN hostname

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejabberd, adonis.js, npm-package

I want to register a user in ejabberd using simple-xmpp package in adonisjs app I get thie error: "Error registering user: Remote domain is not an IDN hostname". I dont know the reason when add another hostname still have the same error

this is my code:

```
async createClient({ response, request }: HttpContextContract) {
    const key = request.input("key");

    const user = await User.query().where({ key }).first();

    if (user) {
      //add client in ejabberd

      xmpp.on("online", () => {
        console.log("online....");
        const iq = new xmpp.Element("stream:stream", {
          xmlns: "jabber:component:accept",
          "xmlns:stream": "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams",
          to: "localhost",
        })
          .c("iq", {
            type: "set",
            id: "reg2",
          })
          .c("query", {
            xmlns: "jabber:iq:register",
          })
          .c("username")
          .t(user.username)
          .up()
          .c("password")
          .t(user.password);

        xmpp.send(iq);
      });

      // Handle response
      xmpp.on("stanza", (stanza) => {
        if (stanza.is("presence")) {
          console.log("Connection established successfully");
        } else if (stanza.is("message") && stanza.attrs.type === "error") {
          const errorElement = stanza.getChild("error");
          const errorText = errorElement.getChildText("text");
          console.error("Error registering user:", errorText);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

anyone can help me in this issue I well appreciate, I search a lot but I did not find a solution

Comment: try it to connect xmpp:
```const xmpp = require('simple-xmpp');

xmpp.connect({
    jid         : user.username,
    password    : user.password,
    host        : 'localhost',
    port        : 5222
});```

Comment: i connected to the xmpp in another file and import xmpp connection object and use it in my controller methods